# How can I make a custom class be displayed in MainWindow.xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I created a custom class that inherits from UIView and I want to display an instance on the screen. However, when I try to link the outlet from the App Delegate to the object I dragged onto the screen (which is that custom class I created) the link cannot be created.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a generic view in your window inside IB, and then, select this new view (let's call it myView) and go to the identity inspector (cmd+4) and write the class name of myView in the Class box inside the inspector. You may be able to link the iboutlet with your view now.